# One of the media query not working

Tags: html, css, debugging, media-queries

Here is part of the code which I need help with:

https://jsfiddle.net/amit1235813/7y3x7uw0/

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #clients {
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        padding-bottom: 125px;
    }   

    #client_logos img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #logo_row_1:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #b3b3b3;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }

    #client_logos .col-sm-4:first-of-type,
    #client_logos .col-sm-4:nth-of-type(2) {
        border-right: 2px solid #b3b3b3;
    }
}
```

As you would notice in the Fiddle, there are two sections: testimonials and clients.

The media query for 'width > 768px' for the 'clients' section does many things e.g. it sets up the background color as a shade of gray. This is not working. Whats going wrong and how can I get it to work?

If this helps: I was playing around with the code and if I remove the media query from the 'testimonial' section, the gray color comes back.

Thank you!

PS: Please ignore any un-funny comment you find in the code. :)

Comment: For me media queries are working. You have used color white. try to change color and you will see changes according to media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing closing parenthesis where max-width: 767px;

```
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
     .testimonial_content {
     color: white;
     padding: 75px 20px 125px 20px;
    }
```

look the screen shot here http://jmp.sh/ZvvUK3r. and here the updated fiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/7y3x7uw0/9/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for some complicated media query based solution and there it is - wrong markup!